# Items in collection view not displaying with MVVM while link is showing

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need help trying to figure out why my collection-view is not displaying the data that its binded to. When I run the application in debug mode the data is being populated into the Viewmodel and binded. When I go to the View.xaml and hover over the source where its binded, it displays.

I have provided the  Model, ModelView, View and the code behind for the View and even a screen shot of the view running in the debugger showing that the bind seems to be working.

I have been stuck for a while any help will be truly appreciated.

[What I see when I run in debug mode showing the view model is binded but just not showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wtTr.png)

**ContactsPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Project_contact.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}">
        
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="TopBanner" Text="Welcome Please wait..." />
            


            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text= "{Binding StringFormat='Welcome You have' }" />
            </StackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsCollectionView2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
               
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" 
                                
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding desc}" 
                                d:Text="Item descripton"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                            
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnContactSelected_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

**ContactsPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using Project_Contact.Models;
using Project_Contact.Views;
using Project_Contact.ViewModels;
using Project_Contact.Services;
using System.Data;

namespace Project_Contact.Views
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ContactsViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
        public ContactStore contactStore { get; set; }

        public ContactsPage()
        {
            contactStore = new ContactStore(DependencyService.Get<Database>());
            viewModel = new ContactsViewModel(contactStore);
            viewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);
            BindingContext = viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var layout = (BindableObject)sender;
            var item = (Item)layout.BindingContext;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));
        }

        async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewContactPage(contactStore)));
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
     
            viewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(true);
           
        }

        async void OnContactSelected_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var layout = (BindableObject)sender;
            var contact = (Contact)layout.BindingContext;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactDetailPage(new ContactDetailViewModel(contactStore,contact)));
        }

    }
}
```

**ContactsPageViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using Project_contact.Models;
using Project_contact.Views;
using Project_contact.Services;

namespace Project_contact.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        public Command LoadContacts { get; private set; }
        public Command LoadDataCommand { get; private set; }
       // public Command load 
        public ContactStore contactStore;
        
        public int  numberofContacts { get; set; }
        public string TopBannerText { get; set; }



        public ContactsViewModel(ContactStore contactStore)
        {
            
            Title = "Browse";
            this.contactStore = contactStore;
            
            
            LoadDataCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadDataCommand());
            
        }

        public  async Task ExecuteLoadDataCommand()
        {
            Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(await contactStore.GetContactsAsync());
            LoadContacts = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadContactsCommand());
           
            TopBannerText = String.Format("Welcome you have {0} contacts  ",numberofContacts);


        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadContactsCommand()
        {
            if (!IsBusy)
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                try
                {
                    if (Contacts.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Contacts.Clear();
                        numberofContacts = 0;
                    }
                    
                    var contacts = await contactStore.GetContactsAsync();
                    foreach (var contact in contacts)
                    {
                        Contacts.Add(contact);
                        numberofContacts++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                }
            }
           
        }

    }
}
```

**Contact.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;

namespace Project_Contact.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string  desc { get; set; }
        public string number {get; set;}

      
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `Contact` class?  Does it have **public properties** for `name` and `desc`?

Comment: And you forgot the most import class... The `Contract` class. How do we know thats you implemented the properties correctly?

Comment: my apologies, I just forgot

Comment: are you **positive** that `name` and `desc` have values?

Comment: yup even they show up when you expand it in debug mode

Comment: try hardcoding the Text value of one of your labels to see if that shows up

Comment: I just tried to hardcode text in desc and name labels and they are not showing up

Comment: then it's probably a problem with your layout, not your binding.  Try specifying a HeightRequest value on your StackLayout and Labels

Comment: I set the HeightRequest to 15 for both and still nothing. However when I set the ItemSource for the Collection View to `viewmodel.Contact` that seems to work but doesn't that defeat the purpose of binding the data?

Comment: try instantiating Contacts in the VM constructor instead of ExecuteLoadDataCommand

Comment: remove d:Text="{Binding .}"

Comment: I'm instantiating Contacts above the VM constructor. I have to use a async method to call the command to load the data because of the database. when I call the command it makes me cast as ` new ObservableCollection<Contact>` or else it gives an error.  I also removed `d:Text="{Binding .}"` when I tried using hardcoded string and it still doesn't load it's no longer in code will update above.